# ArrayList index out of bounds though the accessed index is within bounds

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, arraylist

I am getting an Index Out of Bounds exception for an `ArrayList`. At the point of exception the size() and index seem to be fine when printed. Below is the relevant code. I have a custom table model which is refreshed when a button is clicked.

```
public class CallingClass
{
    public void buttonClicked()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {                   
                dataTableModel.refresh();
            }
        }).start();     
    }
}

public class DataTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    protected ArrayList<Object> data;   

    public DataTableModel()
    {
        data = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int modelRow, int modelColumn)
    {
         // Throws Index Out of Bounds Exception though a println here shows modelRow value within 0 to data.size()-1
         // DataObject is just an interface to support getValue method
        return ((DataObject) data.get(modelRow)).getValue();
    }

    public void refresh()
    {
        reloadData();
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    protected void reloadData()
    {
        ArrayList<TextMessage> messageList = jmsConnection.getMessageList();

        data.clear();

        try
        {
            for(int i=0; i<messageList.size(); ++i)
            {
                data.add(new MyDataObject(messageList.get(i).getJMSMessageID()));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the `DataTableModel.refresh()` runs in a new thread. The call to `fireTableDataChanged` probably causes the `eventQueue` thread to redraw the table, which in turn calls the `getValueAt` method. Here the exception is thrown, despite the `modelRow` value being less than `data.size()`. Not sure how there can be race condition either because the Runnable thread calls the `fireTableDataChanged` after calling `reloadData` (which repopulates the data object). Hence the `data` object should be stable when the eventQueue thread is calling `getValueAt`. Also note the the refresh button is disabled until the runnable thread comes out, to avoid overlapping calls to refresh.

Below is the exception message

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at datatablemodels.DataTableModel.getValueAt(DataTableModel.java:70)
```

If I change the reloadData code slightly, the exception goes away (at least not reproducible yet). My guess is that it is just reducing the odds of the exception.

```
protected void reloadData()
{
    ArrayList<TextMessage> messageList = jmsConnection.getMessageList();

    ArrayList<Object> tempdata = new ArrayList<Object>();

    try
    {
        for(int i=0; i<messageList.size(); ++i)
        {
            tempdata.add(new MyDataObject(messageList.get(i).getJMSMessageID()));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }

    data = tempdata ;
}
```

I am more interested in understanding what is going on here. I do have alternate solutions like `synchronized`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` etc.

Comment: Are you working in a Multithreaded environment?

Comment: Not as such. Only the `new Thread(new Runnable` that you see in the `buttonClicked` is directly created by me. There are no long running threads that I have created.

Comment: @mpathi did you double click ? Its posible to happen if you made a double click.

Comment: Not double click. I too doubted that. Hence I tested slowly with single clicks with 4 to 5 seconds between each click. The issue occurs randomly. Sometimes after 3 clicks and sometimes after 30 clicks.

Comment: You really need to pare this down to a Minimum Complete Verifiable Example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no synchronization, you have no guarantee about when data changes made in the refresh() method - which runs in its own thread - will be visible in other threads running the getValueAt() method, if ever.  For example, the getValueAt() method, or part of it, may run "between" the data.clear() call in the reloadData() method and the repopulation of the data table.

And when you put the println() calls in, they may run before the data.clear() call or after the repopulation of data, even if the data.get() call does not.

The bottom line is, whenever data is touched by more than one thread, as it is here, you must synchronize access to the data, one way or another.

Comment: There is no explicit synchronization. However the `getValueAt()` is triggered (using `fireTableDataChanged`) clearly after the `reloadData` has completed its run. Also I am ensuring that no parallel invocations of `refresh` can be done. Hence it is confusing to me as to how there can be a race between the Runnable thread and the Event thread for the `data` object. The exception message as well gives the index as `3` and size as `10`.

Comment: Without explicit synchronization, the word "after" has no meaning with respect to events in different threads.

Comment: It is the Runnable thread that calls/causes the getValueAt() in the Event Thread in this case. And it does that clearly after repopulating the data object. If Thread1 performs Task1 completely and then requests Thread2 to perform Task2, how can the Task1 and Task2 overlap?